# Spark moving average

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to implement moving average for a dataset containing a number of time series. Each column represents one parameter being measured, while one row contains all parameters measured in a second. So a row would look something like:

```
timestamp, parameter1, parameter2, ..., parameterN
```

I found a way to do something like that using [window functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html), but the following bugs me:

> Partitioning Specification: controls which rows will be in the same partition with the given row. Also, the user might want to make sure all rows having the same value for  the category column are collected to the same machine before ordering and calculating the frame.  **If no partitioning specification is given, then all data must be collected to a single machine**.

The thing is, I don't have anything to partition by. So can I use this method to calculate moving average without the risk of collecting all the data on a single machine? If not, what is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Every nontrivial Spark job demands partitioning. There is just no way around it if you want your jobs to finish before the apocalypse. The question is simple: When it comes time to do the inevitable aggregation (in your case, an average), how can you partition your data in such a way as to minimize shuffle by grouping as much related data as possible on the same machine?

My experience with moving averages is with stocks. In that case it's easy; the partition would be on the stock ticker symbol. After all, the calculation of the 50-Day Moving Average for Stock A has nothing to with that for Stock B, so those data don't need to be on the same machine. The obvious partition makes this simpler than your situation--not to mention that it only requires one data point (probably) per day (the closing price of the stock at the end of trading) while you have one per second.

So I can only say that you need to consider adding a feature to your data set whose sole purpose is to serve as a partition key even if it is irrelevant to what you're measuring. I would be surprised if there isn't one, but if not, then consider a time-based partition on days for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I try to partition by day, wouldn't that "break" the total series, as I'm calculating moving average per pieces (day)? One thing that crosses my mind is to somehow partition the data to save values of each column (parameter) on the same machine, as for this calculation this is the only thing important. But for the next step I would need to combine that columns again into a dataframe to run some ML algorithms. Does that make any sense? So, partition by columns, not by rows.

Comment: BTW, the number of columns is not that small (about 300), so it makes more sense to have 1/300 of data on same machine than all of the data.

Comment: Days was just an example. If you resort to a temporal partition, it's up to you to figure out what that should be. My point was that you probably don't have to, and it sounds like I'm right. It also sounds like you have more data than you need, but regardless, you should probably partition on whichever value is relevant. Do your calculation. Repartition on the next value for the next calculation. Lather. Rinse. Repeat.

Comment: It seems that you have wide experience with this topic, so I'll add a word or two. If by "more data than needed" you have large number of columns in mind, one of the next steps should be to perform PCA to reduce it. As each column actually contains parameter values during time, there's no other value to partition on, except the time column. Do you know whether it is possible ot perform such column based partitioning (with the reasoning explained above), and does all of this make sense to you at the end? I thank you again for the insights.

Comment: And one more question - "My point was that you probably don't have to, and it sounds like I'm right.", why do you think that I don't have to? The whole question was started because of the problem of aggregating data on a single machine, as you are aware of.